# mapping in R with ggmap and ggplot2: (Warning messages: 1: `panel.margin` is deprecated. 2: removed rows with no values)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap

I'm trying to plot latitude and longitude points from an excel sheet over a base map from google earth.

So far I have:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2) 

#Brings up (base map) Map of HallenBeck Creek
HallenBeckMap <- get_map(location="Hallenbeck Creek", maptype = "hybrid", zoom = 14)

library(readxl)

#names excel file as my data
test_HallenBeck_LatLongforR <- read_excel("C:/Users/rofru/Documents/R/test_HallenBeck_LatLongforR.xlsx")

#attempt to overlay points on map but warning message:
#Warning message:Removed 814 rows containing missing values (geom_point)
ggmap(HallenbeckMap, extent = "panel") + 
  geom_point(data = test_HallenBeck_LatLongforR, 
             aes(x = X, y = Y), 
             inherit.aes = FALSE, colour="red")
```

My thought was that my excel data isn't layed out correctly, I have 2 columns labeld X and Y, and X is supposed to be longitude and Y is supposed to be latitude.

This is my first time using R as part of an undergrad research experience, so it's been like learning a whole new language from google. Any help appreciated

Here is a screenshot of what I have in Rstudio with data from excel displayed:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO and R!  I'm not entirely sure what your question is.  Warning messages are just that - alerts that there may be issues you need to think about.  In this case, the 2nd error warns that there is missing data.  This could be latitudes with no corresponding longitude (or vice versa) - or extra rows at the end of the data set (a not-uncommon occurrence when working with Excel).   Either way, they are being ignored, so unless they can bias your data, it's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is the warning message "Warning message:Removed 814 rows containing missing values (geom_point)" because i do have values for all 814 rows. I couldn;t post a picture here because I just signed up but heres a picture I included on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/8stukc/help_with_ggplot_2_overlaying_points_on_base_map/

Comment: How many rows does R claim to have (`nrow(data)`)?  You can also look at `tail(data)` and see what it shows.

Comment: From the data frame visible in your screenshot, perhaps you could try `aes(x = Y, y = X)` in `geom_point()` instead of the other way round?